# Is it possible to create an INotifyCollectionChanged implementation which does not allocate memory on Add?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, allocation, inotifypropertychanged

I am developing a game which makes heavy use of collections which implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Items are added and removed from these lists every frame. The items themselves are pooled, so the are not allocating themselves. However, the addition and removal from the list should raise the `CollectionChanged` event.

To raise this method, my implementation must instantiate a new `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`. The instantiation of the args object, along with the creation of `SingleItemReadOnlyList` instances made inside the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` constructor, are dominating my memory allocations, which are causing somewhat frequent garbage collections.

If I could reuse the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` instance (by re-assigning its internal fields) then I could save a lot of allocation, but all `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` values are readonly so I cannot re-assign these values on the same instance.

Is there a way I can reduce memory pressure while still using the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface? Or do I need to look into some alternative (perhaps custom) solution for notifying when a change occurs?

Comment: If you have pooled items, can't you also have pooled NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs?